# Wildcard to generalize exclusion of sub-deployment war in jboss-deployment-structure.xml?

Tags: java, jboss

How to exclude war having version specified in the name of war? 
There are multiple war in single ear and needs to exclude from only one war.
E.g.

```
<sub-deployment name="AppName-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
    <exclusions>
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8" />
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310" />
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
    </exclusions>
</sub-deployment>
```

Above is my `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`.
When version of AppName change, it requires to change this file. I tried to use wildcard as `AppName-*.war`, but it didn't work. How to write generic `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` or any alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this with `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. Wildcards are not allowed (even in modules/subystems exclusions). Simplest thing is to remove the version from your wars and naming them in a meaningful way.

Comment: Sorry, but I have two sub deployment and want to exclude above modules from both the sub deployment. If exclude in <deployment></deployment>, it's not working. while exclude in both <sub-deployment></sub-deployment>, it's working fine. Is there anyother way to exclude from both sub-deployment without specifying name of war ?? Shouldn't it work when exclude from <deployment></deployment> instead <sub-deployment> ??

Comment: No, in subdeployment you have to specify the deployed app name.

Comment: can I use something like <sub-deployment name="${project.version}">
  <exclusions>
   <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8"/>
   <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310"/>
  </exclusions>
 </sub-deployment>, and if yes, then how and where can I declare value for variable "project.version".

Comment: I don't think you can use maven to write your jboss-deployment-structure -> how are you gonna to replace that property?

Comment: As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456379/how-can-i-force-the-maven-ear-plugin-to-use-a-context-root-variable-within-appli, to change variable in application.xml, can I change in jboss-deployment-structure too ??